# mysql join multiple tables referencing outer queries tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

So, this query is kind of complex since what I want is complex, so the main query generates a list of dates and I need to append 2 things per each row **SPACES** and **MINPRICE**:

1. Get a total of SPACES on each date based on other tables.
2. Get min price based on other tables.

Now it gets more complicated since there’s a column called `combination` that has 2 ids and it’s comma separated, what it does is check if combination exists and search the lower SPACE available between those 2 id’s and replaces default SPACES value. But this should only happened if `greengo_availability_dates_cabins.spaces` doesn't exist.

Also, you should notice `admin_cruises_meta` in some occasions has rows with duplicate cabin this is because is based on month and year, so query checks between `greengo_availability_dates.date_starts` and `admin_cruises_meta_months.month` to match month and show the correct row.

Now I have 3 queries:

1. **MAIN QUERY**: Gets dates list and other columns
2. **SPACES & MINPRICE**: This query needs to be inserted on query #1 but I’m having issues connecting it since referencing outer query's tables in a subquery is not possible.
3. **COMBINATION**: I need this query to work WITHIN query #2 but I’m also having issues with this one.

Live Structure and queries: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6ea3e0/17

```
#QUERY #1
SELECT * FROM `greengo_availability_dates` dates
JOIN `greengo_availability` ava ON dates.id_availability=ava.id
JOIN `admin_cruises` cruises ON cruises.id_post=ava.id_post
LEFT JOIN 
(
select meta.id_cruise as cruiseID, meta.id_rate as rateID, months.`month` as monthID, custom.id_date as dateID, SUM((
    CASE 
        WHEN custom.spaces > 0 THEN custom.spaces
        ELSE (cabins.qty*cabins.max_occupancy)
    END)) AS spaces, MIN((
    CASE 
        WHEN meta.net > 0 THEN (meta.net*(100+cruises.profit_ggt)/100)
        ELSE meta.gross
    END)) AS minPrice
        
         FROM  admin_cruises_meta meta 
          LEFT JOIN admin_cruises cruises ON cruises.id_cruise=meta.id_cruise
          LEFT JOIN admin_cruises_meta_months months ON months.id_cruise_meta= meta.id 
          LEFT JOIN greengo_availability_dates_cabins custom ON custom.id_cruise_meta= meta.id
          LEFT JOIN admin_cruises_cabins cabins ON cabins.id= meta.cabin
        WHERE meta.id_cruise = 1
        AND meta.id_rate = 9
        AND (months.month = DATE_FORMAT('2021-03-01', '%m') OR months.month = 0)
        #GROUP BY meta.id_cruise,meta.id_rate,months.id_cruise_meta
) d ON (d.cruiseID=cruises.id_cruise AND d.rateID=ava.id_rate AND d.dateID = dates.id)
#) d ON (d.cruiseID=cruises.id_cruise AND d.rateID=ava.id_rate AND d.dateID = dates.id AND (d.monthID = DATE_FORMAT(dates.date_starts, '%m') OR d.monthID = 0) )
    
WHERE cruises.id_cruise = 1          
AND ava.id_rate = 9

#QUERY #2
/*select meta.id_cruise as cruiseID, meta.id_rate as rateID, months.`month` as monthID, custom.id_date as dateID, SUM((
    CASE 
        WHEN custom.spaces > 0 THEN custom.spaces
        ELSE (cabins.qty*cabins.max_occupancy)
    END)) AS spaces, MIN((
    CASE 
        WHEN meta.net > 0 THEN (meta.net*(100+cruises.profit_ggt)/100)
        ELSE meta.gross
    END)) AS minPrice
        
         FROM  admin_cruises_meta meta 
LEFT JOIN admin_cruises cruises ON cruises.id_cruise=meta.id_cruise

LEFT JOIN admin_cruises_meta_months months ON months.id_cruise_meta= meta.id 
LEFT JOIN greengo_availability_dates_cabins custom ON custom.id_cruise_meta= meta.id
LEFT JOIN admin_cruises_cabins cabins ON cabins.id= meta.cabin
WHERE meta.id_cruise = 1
AND meta.id_rate = 9 
AND (months.month = DATE_FORMAT('2021-03-01', '%m') OR months.month = 0)*/

#QUERY #3
/*SELECT  MIN((
    CASE 
        WHEN custom.spaces > 0 THEN custom.spaces
        ELSE (cabins.qty*cabins.max_occupancy)
    END)) AS spaces
FROM    greengo_availability ava
        INNER JOIN admin_cruises_meta meta
            ON FIND_IN_SET(meta.id_rate, ava.combination) > 0
    LEFT JOIN admin_cruises_meta_months months ON months.id_cruise_meta= meta.id 
    LEFT JOIN greengo_availability_dates_cabins custom ON custom.id_cruise_meta= meta.id
    LEFT JOIN admin_cruises_cabins cabins ON cabins.id= meta.cabin
    WHERE ava.id = 3*/
```

This is the result now:

```
| id | id_availability | date_starts |  date_ends | status | id | id_post | id_cruise | id_program | id_rate | start_date |   end_date | combination | status | id_cruise | id_post | id_operator |  name | commission_op | profit_ggt | status | cruiseID | rateID | monthID | dateID | spaces | minPrice |
|----|-----------------|-------------|------------|--------|----|---------|-----------|------------|---------|------------|------------|-------------|--------|-----------|---------|-------------|-------|---------------|------------|--------|----------|--------|---------|--------|--------|----------|
|  6 |               3 |  2021-04-01 | 2021-04-11 |      1 |  3 |     462 |    (null) |          9 |       9 | 2020-02-06 | 2022-01-09 |         1,6 |      1 |         1 |     462 |          23 | Yacht |             0 |         15 |      1 |        1 |      9 |       3 |      6 |     14 |  2846.25 |
|  5 |               3 |  2021-03-18 | 2021-03-28 |      1 |  3 |     462 |    (null) |          9 |       9 | 2020-02-06 | 2022-01-09 |         1,6 |      1 |         1 |     462 |          23 | Yacht |             0 |         15 |      1 |   (null) | (null) |  (null) | (null) | (null) |   (null) |
```

Result I'm looking for:

```
| id | id_availability | date_starts |  date_ends | status | id | id_post | id_cruise | id_program | id_rate | start_date |   end_date | combination | status | id_cruise | id_post | id_operator |  name | commission_op | profit_ggt | status | cruiseID | rateID | monthID | dateID | spaces | minPrice |
|----|-----------------|-------------|------------|--------|----|---------|-----------|------------|---------|------------|------------|-------------|--------|-----------|---------|-------------|-------|---------------|------------|--------|----------|--------|---------|--------|--------|----------|
|  6 |               3 |  2021-04-01 | 2021-04-11 |      1 |  3 |     462 |    (null) |          9 |       9 | 2020-02-06 | 2022-01-09 |         1,6 |      1 |         1 |     462 |          23 | Yacht |             0 |         15 |      1 |        1 |      9 |       3 |      6 |     14 |  2846.25 |
|  5 |               3 |  2021-03-18 | 2021-03-28 |      1 |  3 |     462 |    (null) |          9 |       9 | 2020-02-06 | 2022-01-09 |         1,6 |      1 |         1 |     462 |          23 | Yacht |             0 |         15 |      1 |        1 |      9 |       0 | (null) |     16 |  2984.25 |
```

Result from query 2 is this:

```
| cruiseID | rateID | monthID | dateID | spaces | minPrice |
|----------|--------|---------|--------|--------|----------|
|        1 |      9 |       3 |      6 |     14 |  2846.25 |
```

```
| cruiseID | rateID | monthID | dateID | spaces | minPrice |
|----------|--------|---------|--------|--------|----------|
|        1 |      9 |       0 | (null) |     16 |  2984.25 |
```

And if query #3 is applied within query #2 final result should be this, notice the second row shows **2 spaces** since no custom value exists and `combination` is present than it gets the lowest space value between IDS 1 and 6:

```
| id | id_availability | date_starts |  date_ends | status | id | id_post | id_cruise | id_program | id_rate | start_date |   end_date | combination | status | id_cruise | id_post | id_operator |  name | commission_op | profit_ggt | status | cruiseID | rateID | monthID | dateID | spaces | minPrice |
|----|-----------------|-------------|------------|--------|----|---------|-----------|------------|---------|------------|------------|-------------|--------|-----------|---------|-------------|-------|---------------|------------|--------|----------|--------|---------|--------|--------|----------|
|  6 |               3 |  2021-04-01 | 2021-04-11 |      1 |  3 |     462 |    (null) |          9 |       9 | 2020-02-06 | 2022-01-09 |         1,6 |      1 |         1 |     462 |          23 | Yacht |             0 |         15 |      1 |        1 |      9 |       3 |      6 |     14 |  2846.25 |
|  5 |               3 |  2021-03-18 | 2021-03-28 |      1 |  3 |     462 |    (null) |          9 |       9 | 2020-02-06 | 2022-01-09 |         1,6 |      1 |         1 |     462 |          23 | Yacht |             0 |         15 |      1 |        1 |      9 |       0 | (null) |      2 |  2984.25 |
```

Any optimization on queries is appreciated since I'm no expert in MYSQL.

Comment: Sounds like you should use a CTE (or view if you're not using MySQL 8.x)

Comment: Post your code here, not just a sqlfiddle link.

Comment: Code is too long to Post here, that's why I used sqlfiddle

Comment: If the code is too long to post here, consider shortening it.